# Xamarin Android-Video player Black screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm using the Xamarin Android Player emulator to test the app I'm developing. The emulator doesn't play video at all. There's a black screen in place of the videoview.

I've written very simple code just to test the video playback. The code is below:

```
namespace Training
{
    [Activity(Label = "", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
    class videotest : ActionBarActivity
    {
        private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar mToolbar;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.videotest);
            mToolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "";


            var videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://www.printopack.somee.com/Uploaded/Grad2.mp4");
            videoView.SetVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.Start();




        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your url contains video? Seems there is no video on particular url.

Comment: I hear sound but screen is black

Comment: @AhmedRashed that is because your url does'nt contain video, paste it in your browser in you will see that there is no video just sound

Comment: Yes you're right but I'm raising the video but the sound

Comment: this is video : http://www.printopack.somee.com/Uploaded/Grad1.mp4 but i receive can't play this video

Comment: try to test on real device. Emulator consuming too much power to play video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try testing it on a real device. When I was working with video views in Xamarin.Android the same thing happened to me on the emulator but on a real device it worked just fine.